# Trying to git rebase -i and squashing previous commits into one, but it deletes my recent changes

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitlab, rebase

My git history on branch master is as follows:

```
ee040dd Me success project build with all changes I want to keep in this commit since it already merged
1e7282f Me fixing changes   
0a9fb50 Y User some commit    
e03d64e Z User some commit    
5567972 Z User some commit    
a54d24f Me adding new feature    
95d2c28 X User some commit    
7f7b8b2 Me previous commit
```

Basically for a code push I'm trying to send in all updated changes in ee040dd, but instead of sending in several commits by me, I want to squash them all into ***the most recent commit*** due to many, many merging and merge conflicts.

When I do `git rebase -i ee040dd` I get the following doc like usual:

```
pick 7f7b8b2 previous commit
pick a54d24f adding new feature
pick 1e7282 fixing changes
```

When I do:

```
pick 7f7b8b2 previous commit
squash a54d24f adding new feature
squash 1e7282 fixing changes
```

It seems like it squashes all my changes into *previous commit* which is not what I want (since I lost all my changes in ee040dd)

What should I be doing?

Comment: try deleting all the lines and just leave top `pick 7f7b8b2 previous commit` and commit.

Comment: I'm not clear which way up your history is. Is `ee040dd` the most recent or the oldest commit? Why does your `rebase` command only show a portion of the history? Which commits do you want, which commit do you want to keep the message from, and what is the last commit just before the things you want to keep?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your latest commit `ee040dd`, you should keep it as `pick` in rebase interactive windows:

```
pick 7f7b8b2 previous commit
sqush a54d24f adding new feature
squash 1e7282 fixing changes
…
squash 1e7282f Me fixing changes 
pick ee040dd Me success project build with all changes I want to keep in this commit since it already merged
```

Since you have already squash the last commit, now you can cherry-pick it on the top of your `master` branch: `git cherry-pick ee040dd`.

Comment: What do you mean by "keep it as pick"? Here you are changing the latest commit as a squash?

Comment: Would I be able to do all this on master branch (including the cherry-pick)? I don't need to git checkout -b <new branch>?

Comment: When you use `git rebase -i`, you squashed `ee040dd`, actually it should use `pick` (as I listed in my answer)  based on your requriment. And Yes, you can use `git cherry-pick ee040dd` on master branch, then you will get the recently changes back on master branch.